# SELECT statement in Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle12c

I have a SQL Server script like

```
declare @num int
begin
--//........while loops/ if conditions...
--//........remove code for simplicity
select num from tbl where cnd = @num;
end
```

I have done this in Oracle;

```
Declare v_num number;
begin
--//........while loops/ if conditions...
--//........remove code for simplicity
select num from tbl where cnd = v_num;
end;
/
```

I am getting an error

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

The whole sql server query is about 500 line which is having may variables declared and assigned.... At the end of the script there is a select statement using many of those variables and multiple tables. How could I get that select statement work in Oracle?

Comment: We would actually need more code to understand what you want. Do you want to assign num to v_num ? Is v_num filled by another part of the code ? What is @num ?

Comment: The whole `sql query` is about `500 line` which is having may variables declared and assigned.... At the end of the script there is a `select` statement using many of those variables and multiple tables. How could i get that `select` statement work in `Oracle`.

Comment: Did you get a blessing from the woodoo prist? How can we know what is wrong if you don't show thr *Relevant* code?

Comment: In your Oracle code you declare a variable v_num but use a variable @num. Is this a typo?  I dont know oracle enough, but it is possible that the a select in pl/sql must select into a cursor or another table. At least the error message suggests that.

Comment: @Peter Paul Kiefer Thanks its a `typo`. corrected it.

Comment: The rest of my comment is more interesting I think ;-). Try `SELECT num INTO number from tbl where ...` I hope number is correct. Perhaps you have to declare another variable. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use `v_num` from decalre block you should rewrite your code follows:

```
Declare v_num number;
begin
--//........while loops/ if conditions...
--//........remove code for simplicity
select num from tbl where cnd = v_num ;
end;
/
```

If you use follows:

```
Declare v_num number;
begin
--//........while loops/ if conditions...
--//........remove code for simplicity
select num from tbl where cnd = :v_num ;
end;
/
```

you must insert value into parametr `v_num`

if you want select value from `num` to `v_num` you should rewrite you code follows:

```
Declare v_num number;
begin
--//........while loops/ if conditions...
--//........remove code for simplicity
select num into v_num from tbl;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Declare v_num number;
begin
--//........while loops/ if conditions...
--//........remove code for simplicity
select num from tbl where cnd = :v_num;
end;
/
```

Comment: Even if i do `select num from tbl` I am getting the error `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`